# How to concat a variable into some <asp: .. /> attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on small web form,in C#/ASP.NET. I want to store the errors messages into variables of C# class; something like this:

```
public static class ErrorMessages { 
 public static string fooX = "baa"; 
 // etc..
}
```

And then concat it in some attribute of an `ASP` tag:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="baain"
     ErrorMessage= *ErrorMessages.fooX*
 />
```

Is it possible? if yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the aspx page you may try:

```
ErrorMessage='<%# ErrorMessages.fooX %>'
```

In your code behind on page load call `DataBind();`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am not sure about concatenating the aspx part of the page, you can set the ErrorMessage property of your RegularExpressionValidator in the code behind. Something like:

```
RegularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Your message";
```

or

```
RegularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.fooX;
```

Comment: I tried exactly it: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
              ControlToValidate="path"
              ErrorMessage="<%# foo.ErrorMessages.WrongPath %>"
               ValidationExpression="someregex"
             />`
It compile, but I don't get any error message. But if I replace to `ErrorMessage="error"` it will works fine.

Comment: @Jack, try calling `DataBind();` in your page load, check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this, is to create your own custom expression builder.

The ExpressionBuilder class is the base class for expression builders, such as the AppSettingsExpressionBuilder class, that create code expressions during page parsing.

Expression builders parse declarative expressions and create code to retrieve values bound to a control property. In no-compile scenarios, an expression builder that supports a no-compile feature evaluates the expression during run time.

Please see the link from msdn for more detailed explanation and example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, have you tried this:

```
<%= YourNamespace.YourConstant %>
```

Or (.Net 4, this option will automatically encode the text)

```
<%: YourNamespace.YourConstant %>
```

There are several operators:

- `<%#` Used for data binding
- `<%$` Used for expressions, not code; often seen with DataSources:
- `<%=` Returns a string
- `<%:` Same as `<%=` but it auto-html-encodes the value within the tag

### Edit 1

Well I just tested and it appears that you cannot use inline code with server controls...

So alternative approaches:

- Simply assign the value using code behind

  ```
   this.myRegularExpressionValidator.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.Foo;
  ```
- Use resources instead. With resources you will gain many benefits like localization for your site and since resources are simply xml files, you can drop them in your site without recompile (assuming you are not using satellite assemblies to store your resources)

  ```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource, MyResource %>" />
  ```

  Where

  - `Resource` refers to the global resource file
  - `MyResource` refers to the key in the resource file containing the text

  The global resources must be placed in the `App_GlobalResources` ASP.Net special folder, as an example the resource file name: `Resource.resx`

  Example of the resource file

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
    <data name="MyResource" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>My error message</value>
    </data>
  </root>
  ```

  The resource files can be added and managed using Visual Studio so you do not have to deal manually with the XML

Comment: Can you give me an example? it does not works for me: `ErrorMessage=<%= ErrorMessages.FooX %>`

Comment: Include the namespace of your class and enclose it with `""`

Comment: Something like this? `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
              ControlToValidate="..."
              ErrorMessage=<%= ErrorMessages.InvalidPath %>
               ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{3}[-.]\d{4}$"
             />`

Comment: It should be something like that but it appears that it does not work on server controls... `ErrorMessage="<%= RootNamespace.ErrorMessages.InvalidPath %>"` Gimme a sec